# CKModifyRecordsOperation not deleting records

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperation, cloudkit

Following a query, I collected an array of CKRecordID objects, which I wished to delete from my database. It actually contains the ID for every object in the database right now, so it's easy to see when there are entries there.

I first tried to delete these through an operation, like so:

```
let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: nil, recordIDsToDelete: recordIDsToDelete)
operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = {
    (savedRecords: [CKRecord]?, deletedRecordIDs: [CKRecordID]?, error: NSError?) in
    print("complete! deleted record IDs: \(deletedRecordIDs)")
}

self.operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
```

But despite getting the callback listing all the recordIDs I expected, upon checking on the dashboard all of the items still remained.

So I tried this via different means, through a block, which I'd rather avoid since it doesn't put the work into an operation:

```
for recordID in recordIDsToDelete {
    publicDB.deleteRecordWithID(recordID, completionHandler: {
        (recordID: CKRecordID?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        print("deleted record id: \(recordID)")
        print("error: \(error)")
    })
}
```

This works. I can of course make my own operation from that code, but it seems like I'm missing something as to why the already-existing operation doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here...

CKModifyRecordsOperation inherits from CKDatabaseOperation, which has a database property which defaults to the private database, so those operations were being performed on a different database. I simply set the database to be the public one, and it all works:

`operation.database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase`

Comment: Another (better) solution is to add the operation directly to the database: `CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.addOperation(operation)` instead of using your own queue.

Comment: The lack of any kind of error in any of the callbacks seems like a really bad choice.  Thanks for the tip here.  I was about ready to give up on it.